# Stripe API Unhandled Rejection Response Error

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions, stripe-payments

I am simply using the Stripe API to create a subscription in firebase cloud functions.

I am getting the errors: Unhandled rejection 
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.

Here is my index.ts:

```
export const subscribe = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    res.header('Content-Type','application/json');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
    //respond to CORS preflight requests
    if (req.method == 'OPTIONS') {
        res.status(204).send('');
    }

    stripe.subscriptions.create({
        customer: req.body.sid,
        items: [
          {
            plan: "plan_123123123",
          },
        ]
      }, function(err, subscription) {
          // asynchronously called
          if (err) {
            return res.send(err)
          }
          else {
              return res.send(subscription)
          }
        }
      );
});
```

Comment: try a `return;` after `res.status(204).send('');`, otherwise, you'll be calling `res.send()` twice in case of `OPTIONS` (pre-flight) request

Comment: Wow. I owe you my life. A 8+ hour bug...so simple thank you!

Comment: added answer below. glad I was helpful :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
if (req.method == 'OPTIONS') {
    res.status(204).send('');
}
```

try:

```
if (req.method == 'OPTIONS') {
    return res.status(204).send('');
}
```

otherwise, you'll be calling `res.send()` twice in case of OPTIONS (pre-flight) request, causing the error.